# Exercise in Well Orderings

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

Prove that if $\prec$ is a well-ordering on a set X and if  $Y \subseteq X$, then $\prec_Y=\{(x,y) \mid (x \in Y) \wedge (y \in Y) \wedge (x \prec y)\}$ is a well ordering on Y.

I am a little confused on where to start. Also I don't really know what $\prec_Y$ really means.

Comment: "I don't really know what $\prec≺_Y$ really means." It means *exactly* what you wrote in line 2. Nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: Alright do you mind telling me if I got the reasoning down? So I need to show that $\prec$ is a well ordering on Y, and when I do that I need to show that $x$ is the smallest element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation $\prec_Y$ is the restriction of $\prec$ to $Y$. This means that $\prec_Y$ is only defined when both elements are from $Y$, and then it agrees with the original $\prec$.

Now you have to show that $(Y,\prec_Y)$ is a well-ordered set. This means linearly ordered, and if $A\subseteq Y$ is non-empty, then it has a minimal element. Note that all these properties follow from the fact that $(X,\prec)$ is a well-ordered set.

Comment: Suppose ($X, \prec$) is a well-ordered set. Because $Y \subseteq X$, then $\prec \subseteq \prec_Y$. Do I have a good start?

Comment: @Johambo No, you copied a typo from my answer (which I know fixed). And I wouldn't say $Y\subseteq X$ is the main reason why $\prec _Y\subseteq \prec$, but it is necessary.

Comment: How about this for a start? Suppose $\prec$ is a well ordering on the set $X$. Then for all $\forall Y \subseteq X: \exists x \in Y: \forall y \in Y: x \preceq y$.

Comment: @Johambo: Your assumption is that $\prec$ is a well-ordering of $X$. You don't need to "suppose" it. Write down the definition of a well-order. Then verify that $\prec_Y$ satisfies these requirements. Remember to *use* the fact that $\prec$ satisfies these requirements (on a larger domain).

Comment: $\prec$ is a well-ordering on the set X if for every non empty subset $A \subseteq X$, there is an element $x \in A$ such that $\forall b \in A ((a=b) \vee (a \prec b))$. Since $\prec_Y \subseteq \prec$ then what it true for the larger set is true for the smaller set. So $\prec_Y$ satisfies the requirements of a well ordered set.

Comment: @Johambo: You forgot the linear order part, but let's assume that you already know that a restriction of a linear order to a subset of the domain is a linear order of that subset; In your comment you didn't prove anything. You have to prove that $\prec_Y$ is a well-ordering of $Y$. So you need to show that if $A\subseteq Y$ is a non-empty set, then there is some $a\in A$ such that for all $b\in A$, $a=b$ or $a\prec_Y b$. Just saying "it's true for this so it's true for that" does not constitute as a proof (at least not at the level where you get asked this sort of question.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry about being so late. But I revisited this problem and made some sense of what you were saying. So I need to show that $\prec_Y$ is transitive and asymmetric. I also need to show that given any $x,y\in Y$, either $x=y$, $x\prec_Y y$ or $y\prec_Y x$. And finally that given any non-empty $S\subseteq Y$, there is a $x\in S$ such that for all $y\in S$, if $x\neq y$, then $x\prec_Y y$.

Comment: @Johambo: That's good.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Check out my edit

Comment: So for showing that $\prec_Y$ is transitive. I was thinking of starting out with $(x,y) \in \prec_Y$ and $(y,z) \in \prec_Y$.

Comment: @Johambo: You need to show that $\prec_Y$ is transitive and *irreflexive*. The rest is fine. And proving transitivity often starts with picking two such ordered pairs. Now use the fact that $x,y,z\in Y$ and that $\prec_Y\subseteq\prec_X$. The rest of the proof is a repeated application of this principle (that your elements are from $Y$ and that $\prec_Y$ is a subset of $\prec_X$).

Comment: Irreflexive: Let $(x,y) \in \prec_Y$. So $x \in Y$ and $y \in Y$. Thus $x \in X$ and $y \in X$ because $Y \subseteq X$. Notice that x cannot equal y, so $\prec_Y$ is not reflexive.

Comment: @Johambo: Yes, that's the general sentiment. Note, however, that "not reflexive" is not the same thing as "irreflexive".

Comment: $(x,y) \in \prec_Y$ and $(y,z) \in \prec_Y$. Thus $(x,y) \in Y$ and $(y,z) \in Y$. Since $Y \subseteq X$, then $(x,y) \in X$ and $(y,z) \in X$. Considering X is a well ordered set, $(x,y) \in \prec_X$ and $(y,z) \in \prec_X$. Thus $\prec_Y \subseteq \prec_X$. I don't know how this means its transitive though.

Comment: @Johambo: First note that it's not $(x,y)\in Y$ it's $x$ and $y$ which are in $Y$. Similarly $z$. Since $\prec_X$ is transitive, and $(x,y),(y,z)\in\prec_X$ what does it mean? Now we have that $x$ and $z$ are in $Y$... and?

Comment: Oh I think I know where you are getting at. Since we are trying to prove that $\prec_Y$ is transitive, we should show that it is a subset of a relation that we know to be transitive by definition, $\prec_X$. So for what you are asking me: $x \prec_X y$ and $y \prec_X z$. Since $\prec_X$ is transitive, then $x \prec_X z$.

Comment: Yes, so $(x,z)\in\prec_X$. How do you get from that it is in $\prec_Y$ as well?

Comment: But then, $\prec_Y \subseteq \prec_X$ so $(x,z) \in \prec_Y$.

Comment: @Johambo: No, $\Bbb N\subseteq\Bbb R$. Does that mean that $\sqrt2$ is a natural number? To have $(x,z)\in\prec_Y$ you need to show that $(x,z)$ satisfies the definition of $\prec_Y$. And to do that you need to connect the dots that I have left in previous comments.

Comment: Well first off, I know that $(x,z) \in Y$ since it $x,z$ are elements in Y.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fix $x,y,z \in Y$. Let $x \prec_Y y $ and $ y \prec_Y z$. Since $Y \subseteq X$ then we know that $x,y,z \in X$. By the definition of $\prec_Y$, $(x,y) \in \prec_X$ and $(y,z) \in \prec_X$.  Since we know that $\prec_X$ is transitive by definition, then we can say that $(x,z) \in \prec_X$. Notice that $x,z  \in Y$, and $ x \prec z$. Therefore $x \prec_Y z$ by the definition of $\prec_Y$. Ergo $\prec_Y$ is transitive.

Comment: @Johambo: (1) Don't write $(x,z)\in Y$ (as in the first comment). It's not true. $0$ and $1$ are elements of $\{0,1\}$. But is $(0,1)\in\{0,1\}$? No. (2) If you fix $x,y,z\in Y$ then you can't say "Let $x\prec_Y y$ and $y\prec_Y z$" anymore. What if the $x,y,z$ that you have *fixed* don't satisfy these relations, what if $z\prec_Y x$? Other than that, the proof is okay.